# How to install from source PHP5.5, Apache2.4, Mysql5.5

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4

i have a centos 6.5 running locally as my webserver via virtual box, i only used this to test my website and wanted to simulate the real server, as much as possible i wanted to have the latest php, apache and mysql on my webserver, just that. however, centos has a default httpd (apache) @ v2.2, and mysql 5.1, i know, just update it, but yum repos don't have it yet, though third party repos have it but there is this problem updating from different repos that **phpmyadmin starts to say php mysql library has 5.1 and mysql server has 5.5 thing**. in order to avoid that kind of warning i decided to install all of these from source.. compile then install, however i didn't find any tutorials, threads to show me how, im kinda new in compiling from source since all i ever did was get it from repo. just know i wanted to avoid any warnings.

- is there any tutorials/pointers from you guys that you can recommend? like how to install those programs (php,apache,mysql)

PS: i don't want to use xampp/lampp since i just need these 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would urge you not to compile it from source yourself. It's harder to maintain and almost impossible to upgrade correctly.

You can get php and mysql 55 packages from IUS repo. That's the repo that maintained by RackSpace guys, and packages are high quality and security maintained.

https://iuscommunity.org/pages/Repos.html

Regarding latest Apache, take a look at REMI's collection:

https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/

With only 2 additional repos you would be able to accomplish your goal. If you have trouble installing it, I can write a more detailed howto, with steps. Beauty of CentOS/RHEL is that so many guys use it, that you can find prepackaged versions of any software for almost anything, and if you can't, RPM is easy to rebuild from SPEC file so you can always try backporting it from Fedora.

Regarding your comment about phpmyadmin 5.1  vs 5.5, usually when you upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5, 5.5 packages install compat-mysql51 (or similarly named package) which brings compatible libraries of MySQL version 5.1, so that CentOS programs that are built with 5.1 support continue to work as expected and rely on that compatibility library. So you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: hmmm @phpmyadmin 5.1->5.5 if thats the case, might as well install from those repo if it woudnt cause any trouble... thanks a lot man.. and yeah those repo helped a lot.. but i've used the repo i am using in the past buy yeah thanks for the insight man

Comment: I am pretty sure that jkaluza is not remi.